# Previous month data not showing up when calculated by the date in dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, daxstudio

I need to be able to roll this measure up by month  but when I use PREVIOUSMOTH function my data goes blank when I drill up by month. any work around would be greatly appreciated. My guess is I just need to take out blanks and then data will show. Please see current code below:

.Turnover Rate Prev = CALCULATE([.Turnover Rate],PREVIOUSDAY(date table/column))

Inline image

[image]

Comment: What your [.Turnover Rate] do? Can you add some dummy data - source and desired output?

Comment: basically it calculates employee terminate rate over time